# Not able to hide the Android title bar outside the onCreate method

Tags: android, eclipse, android-titlebar

I'm implementing an application that runs always in fullscreen and with no title bar.
There's a situation where the user clicks on a button and use the voice recognition feature API. An android native window is called to analise the user's voice. But then, the title bar gets visible again. The problem is that I can't hide it again, since the method for hiding it  just works in the onCreate method.

Here's is method where I call the voice API, and the title bar gets visible again.

```
public void VoiceCaptureButtonClick(View v) {

       //- The title bar is properly hidden at this point.

       //Code for calling the voice recognition API: 
       Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
       intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
       intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
       startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);


      //- Now the title bar is visible again, and I don't manage to hide it anymore.
      // if I use the method requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      // I run into a exception : "requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

    }
```

**Edited:**

Here's the code I'm using for hiding the title bar and making the application full-screen,
which works perfectly, until the point I call the method above.

```
<application
 ...
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 ...
</application>
```

I'm using android 2.3.3 and Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar."` to your `<activity>` in the manifest to remove the title bar fully. Something like:

```
<activity
      android:name=".Foo"   
      android:label="@string/foo" 
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.">
```

EDIT:

I see now. When you call `startActivityForResult()`, your application is no longer in control as you have started the Voice Recognition Activity. Due to this, your styling (hiding of the title bar etc) is no longer in play, and Android displays all that again.

You cannot use `requestFeature()` here as Android can only make those changes before it inflates your layout.

There doesn't seem to be a solution for this, as your app isn't in control when `startActivityForResult()` has been called.